# Remote app on iPad regularly loses connection to Mac

Tags: itunes, ipad, mac-mini, remote.app

I'm using a Mac mini with an external 3TB hard drive to run my audio system.
I'm controlling iTunes on the Mac mini using Apple's Remote app on my iPad.

My problem is that Remote seems to lose the connection with the Mac repeatedly,
so in turn I lose the ability to control my music. Sometimes it's just slow and the message reads it's connecting with the shared file, then it finds it, other time it tells me it can't find it at all. The Mac is set to not sleep. What can I do to keep the connection between my Mac and the Remote app on my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

- Try the usual 'turn it off and on again' things first.
- Turn on "Stay Connected" in the Remote app's setting
  [image]
- Try switching your wireless channel, frequency, or both.

Comment: The Stay Connected setting has been On. I tried turning on Remote Management in Sharing, which took over Screen Sharing. So far, at least for the past hour or so,I've stayed connected. I'll see what happens after it's idle for a few hours. Hopefully, it will wake up the mini which acts as if it's sleeping even though the light isn't fading in and out. Thanks...